# jQuery validation not working in Thickbox display ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, thickbox

I'm using Thickbox 3.1 with jQuery 1.3.2 with the Validation plugin and all works great when I run the pages individually but when I use Thickbox the page popup (As it should) but the validation on the page now doesn't work (Inside the Thickbox), any help on this would be great.

BTW the strange thing is that Thickbox looks to be working inside the Thickbox but not the validation (Which is on the page itself).

Adding Code:

> **page1.html (JavaScript)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#page1Form").validate({
        rules: {
            "field1": {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },
            "field2": {
                required: true
            }
        },
        errorElement: "div"
    });
});
```

> **index.html (Thickbox link)**

```
<a href="page1.html" class="thickbox">Page 1</a>
```

I can view source on the Thickbox popup and I see all the JS code and libraries are there but it's not running the validation in the Thickbox Popup.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Does it happen only in a specific browser? Any sample JS code for us or HTML so we know what we are talking about?

Comment: No errors and loading the page itself via URL instead of Thickbox the validation works.

Comment: BTW I can't load it in an iFrame needs to be ajax call

Comment: Wow.. there's nothing wrong with your code or method. So, you're saying the content of the thickbox is not in an iframe? If so, there would be no reason to attach jQuery and the validation plugin to 'page1.html'. I doubt that would cause a problem, but, it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply KyleFarris but could you elaborate on what's "worth a try"?

Comment: Oh, sorry... try not attaching the jQuery and validation plugin files to 'page1.html'. While I highly doubt double-including the scripts will cause a problem, it's worth trying I guess.

Comment: I found that if I do use the iFrame it works as expected but if I do the Ajax call it does not work. Any thoughts as to why this would be? I would like to NOT use the iFrame.

Thanks in advance for all efforts,
--Phill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the even handelers are being set on page load, so they aren't set on the thickbox generated html. Can't you set a callback to start the validationi after the thickbox ajaxloads the content?

Comment: Thanks after looking into the callback I think it will work. for now I got the go ahead to use the iFrame which worked as expected. Thanks again.